# How to select zero when there is no common value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which returns the most common value for each gid. The code is follows:

```
select distinct on(gid) gid, max_height
from (
select gid, max_height, count(id) as freq
from my_table
group by 1, 2
) s
order by gid, freq desc, max_height desc
```

For the following sample data:

```
gid id  max_height
3   1   19.3
3   2   19.3
3   3   20.3
3   4   20.3
3   5   19.3
3   6   19.3
3   7   21.4
3   8   21.4
3   9   21.4
3   10  21.4
3   11  21.4
3   12  21.4
22  1   23.1
22  2   23.1
22  3   23.1
22  4   23.1
22  5   23.1
22  6   23.1
22  7   22.1
22  8   22.1
22  9   22.1
22  10  22.1
22  11  22.1
22  12  22.1
29  1   24.1
29  2   22.2
29  3   25.3
29  4   15.4
29  5   17.2
29  6   18.9
29  7   2.5
29  8   3.5
29  9   25.1
29  10  27.1
29  11  5.5
29  12  6.5
```

Each gid is unique and it contains 12 values of ID and max_height. I need to modify above code such that it should return 0.0 when there is no most common value (mode) for any gid. Based on this, the desired output could be:

```
gid    max_height
3      21.4
22     23.1
29     0.0
```

Can anyone provide some pointers to get my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a condition on `freq` in select list:

```
select distinct on(gid) 
    gid, case when freq > 1 then max_height else 0.0 end as max_height
from (
    select gid, max_height, count(id) as freq
    from my_table
    group by 1, 2
    ) s
order by gid, freq desc, max_height desc;

 gid | max_height 
-----+------------
   3 |       21.4
  22 |       23.1
  29 |        0.0
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand "most common value".  29 has a most common value -- in fact many of them.  This is called the mode.

If you want to know if the mode is not unique, then here is one Postgres'y way:

```
select gid,
       (case when mode() over (partition by gid order by max_height desc) <> 
                  mode() over (partition by gid order by max_height asc)
             then 0.0
             else mode() over (partition by gid order by max_height desc)
        end) as most_freq
from my_table
group by gid;
```

This checks for the uniqueness of the mode, using Postgres's built-in function.

Comment: ERROR:  function mode() does not exist. I got this error while trying to test your code.